Error (Xcode): Unexpected duplicate tasks. Flutter iOS App launch failed
When I am trying to run my flutter project in iOS simulator. I'm getting this error: Error (Xcode): Unexpected duplicate tasks.Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
I have checked similar problem on stackoverflow but any of them are not helpful in this case. I have checked Compile sources and Copy Bundle Resources section, there is not duplicacy.
cleaned the project and tried to rebuild it, deleted the iOS project and recreated it but didn't worked out
